# How to stop poller in spring integration while processing Files

Tags: spring, spring-integration

```
<bean id="inFileHandler"
    class="com.yahoo.FileProcessHandler" />

<bean id="executorService" class="java.util.concurrent.Executors" factory-method="newSingleThreadExecutor" destroy-method="shutdownNow" />

<int:channel id="inChannel" />

<int:channel id="outChannel">
    <int:queue capacity="5" />
</int:channel>

<bean id="sftpFactory"
    class="org.springframework.integration.sftp.session.DefaultSftpSessionFactory">
    <property name="host" value="${SFTP_HOST}"></property>
    <property name="port" value="${SFTPPORT}"></property>
    <property name="user" value="${SFTPUSERNAME}"></property>
    <property name="password" value="${SFTPPASSWORD}"></property>
</bean>

<sftp:inbound-channel-adapter id="ftpInBound" channel="inChannel"
    session-factory="sftpFactory" 
    delete-remote-files="true" remote-directory="/Files"
    local-directory="file:C:/Bhaji">
    <int:poller id="poller" fixed-rate="10000"/>
</sftp:inbound-channel-adapter>

<int:service-activator input-channel="inChannel"
    output-channel="nullChannel" ref="inFileHandler" method="handler" />
```

and the FileProcess handler is

```
 @Autowired
    private ExecutorService executorService;

    private static Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(FileProcessHandler.class);

    public File handler(File input) {
        **//Doing some time taking process**
        return input;
}
```

here while doing the time taking process i don't want to poll the SFTP inbound-channel-adapter. after completion of time taken process the poller should start automatically.

Is there any way to do this ? is there any way to achieve it?

Answer (score 0):

What are using the executor service for - let the flow run on the poller thread and the next poll won't happen until the current poll completes.

Comment: Actual requirement is from sftp i have to copy mutiple files at a time and i have to process the files using spring-batch one by one.Can you please elaborate how can i run it in poller thread?

Comment: Hey will you explain how can we access the poller thread? would you guide me to run this.

Comment: What do you mean by "access" ? You can stop/start the adapter at will. You can restart it when your last task is complete - the framework can't do that for you.

Comment: OK.can you please explain how can i stop the adapter when ever a file is received and how can i restart the adapter when the process on file was done?

Comment: Use a [control bus](http://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/reference/html/system-management-chapter.html#control-bus) and send `@ftpInBound.stop()` and `...start()`.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like it would be enough for you to use `fixed-delay` instead of `fixed-rate` on the `<poller>` and do the task in a `TaskScheduler` Thread. In this case you will have only one process at a time. And the next one will start only after the finish of previous.

Comment: <int:poller fixed-delay="${alloc.delay}">


for 1 min delay alloc.delay=60000

Comment: I am not asking for this config.i am looking for full config.this poller config i already mentioned in question.